# Angular 2 Services - $mdMedia

Tags: angular2-services, angular-material2

Is there an Angular 2 service that is similar to $mdMedia? I need to show or hide a button based on the size of the window (if the window is the same size as the screen, I want to hide it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this could help you.

**resize.service.js**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class ResizeService {
    public window = new BehaviorSubject(null);

    constructor() {
        window.onresize = (e) => {
            this.window.next(e.target);
        };
    }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {ResizeService} from './resize/resize.service';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
    providers: [ResizeService]
})

export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private resizeService: ResizeService) {
        resizeService.window.subscribe((val) => {
            if (val) {
                console.log(val.innerWidth);
            }
        });

    };
}
```

The service uses BehaviourSubject. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40231605/782358) for a description of what it is. Also see https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/subjects/behavior_subject/index.html

The component subscribes to the BehaviourSubject (window) and gets the updated values when the screen size changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use and should use flex-layout:

official https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Adaptive-Layouts#core-directives--responsive-features

```
import {ObservableMedia} from '@angular/flex-layout';

@Component({
  selector : 'my-mobile-component',
  template : `
      <div *ngIf="media.isActive('xs')">
         This content is only shown on Mobile devices
      </div>
      <footer>
         Current state: {{ }}
      </footer>
  `
})
export class MyMobileComponent {
  public state = '';
  constructor(public media:ObservableMedia ) {
    media.asObservable()
      .subscribe((change:MediaChange) => {
        this.state = change ? `'${change.mqAlias}' = (${change.mediaQuery})` : ""
      });
  }
}
```