# Angular cli generate a service and include the provider in one step

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular-cli

It is possible generate a service with angular cli and add it as a **provider** in the **app.module.ts** in a single step or using an special option in the **ng g service** command?

When a execute:

```
$ ng g service services/backendApi
installing service
  create src/app/services/backend-api.service.spec.ts
  create src/app/services/backend-api.service.ts
  WARNING Service is generated but not provided, it must be provided to be used
```

[image: WARNING Service is generated but not provided, it must be provided to be used]

Next to it, (and according to the WARNING message) I usually add it to **provider** section on **app.module.ts** using the text editor:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ....
  ],
  providers: [BackendApiService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

It is possible to do it with a single step, to automatize this?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Actually, it is possible to provide the service (or guard, since that also needs to be provided) when creating the service.

The command is the following...

`ng g s services/backendApi --module=app.module`

**Edit**

It is possible to provide to a feature module, as well, you must give it the path to the module you would like.

`ng g s services/backendApi --module=services/services.module`

Comment: Is there a way to provide it in multiple places as well?

Comment: Generally, it's bad practice to provide a service in more than one module. That said, the CLI doesn't allow this with the `--module` flag. You could do it yourself, however, but I'd recommend providing it at a higher level in your application.

Comment: Is enough with `ng g s services/userlist --module=app`

Comment: Correct. It's part of the feature I added way back when. `app`, `app.module`, and `app.module.ts` all work. If it contains a path prefix, you can just do `path/to/app` (with all the variations mentioned).

Original:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/commit/314167325486ffc466326fa015d769aed9555c0b#diff-fd1947ec7dd20fca42dd3b6d66fc1b89

Move to Devkit (with updates):
https://github.com/angular/devkit/blob/master/packages/schematics/angular/utility/find-module.ts

Comment: The --module flag has been dropped from `$ ng g s` as of Angular 6.  See https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/generate-service and also Simon_Weaver's answer.

Comment: The answer is incorrect for angular 6 at least. Check @StuttonY's comment.

Comment: I did the exact thing you said and it returns me this error ` Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(module).` I'm using Angular 6

Comment: Adding provider to module doesn't work with angular 6.Service creation using Angular CLI will just generate the service will not be provided, it must be provided to be used.

Comment: '--module' option is still available for 'component' and 'directive', but as far as I can see not for service anymore. c.f. https://angular.io/cli/generate

Comment: Explanation on the removal [SuttonY mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42748773#comment89235115_42763164) is on the [Angular CLI github Issues page here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11079#issuecomment-397293382). "_Closing this as since Angular version 6 the preferred way to create a services is to specify on the service that it should be provided in the application root. This is done by setting `providedIn` to root on the service's `@Injectable` decorator. With this approach the module is redundant since the the service never gets registered in the `ngModule`._"

Answer (score 64):

#### Angular 6+ Singleton Services

The [recommended approach](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services) for a singleton service for Angular 6 and beyond is :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class UserService {
}
```

In fact the CLI `--module` switch [doesn't even exist any more](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/generate-service) for registering a service at the `app` level because it doesn't need to modify `app.module.ts` anymore.

This will create the above code, without needing to specify a module.

```
ng g s services/user
```

So if you **don't** want your service to be a singleton you must remove the `providedIn` code yourself - and then add it manually to `providers` for a component or lazy loaded module. Doesn't look like there is currently a switch to not generate the `providedIn: 'root'` part so you need to manually remove it.

Comment: I often add --help or --dryRun at the end of an ng command before I commit to executing it. Great way to learn and remember the options. Note that dryrun lowercase doesn’t work!

Comment: Simon_Weaver -dry-run is another syntax

Comment: You can also provide a service in a module: eg. `providedIn: UserModule`. https://angular.io/guide/providers

Answer (score 3):

Looks like in Angular v11 and higher, we don't have option "s" anymore:

```
ng g service services/backendApi
```

or like that:

```
ng g service services/backendApi --flat --skipTests=true
```

Comment: `skipTests` has been renamed to `skip-tests`. [refer for more info](https://angular.io/cli/generate#service)

Answer (score 2):

> Specify paths

```
--app
  --one
    one.module.ts
    --services

  --two
    two.module.ts
    --services
```

> Create **Service** with new folder in module **ONE**

```
ng g service one/services/myNewServiceFolderName/serviceOne --module one/one

--one
  one.module.ts // service imported and added to providers.
  --services
    --myNewServiceFolderName
      serviceOne.service.ts
      serviceOne.service.spec.ts
```

Answer (score 2):

slight change in syntax from the accepted answer for Angular 5 and angular-cli 1.7.0

```
ng g service backendApi --module=app.module
```

Comment: I just checked with a test project, and my answer still works. Is there something I'm missing? The only difference I can tell is you will generate a service in app/ vs mine which generates in app/services (where @Pablo Ezequiel asked).

Answer (score 1):

**Add a service to the Angular 4 app using Angular CLI**

An Angular 2 service is simply a javascript function along with it's associated properties and methods, that can be included (via dependency injection) into Angular 2 components.

To add a new Angular 4 service to the app, use the command `ng g service serviceName`. On creation of the service, the Angular CLI shows an error:

[image: WARNING Service is generated but not provided, it must be provided to be used]

To solve this, we need to provide the service reference to the `src\app\app.module.ts` inside `providers` input of `@NgModule` method.

Initially, the default code in the service is:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ServiceNameService {

  constructor() { }

}
```

A service has to have a few public methods.

Answer (score 1):

In Angular 5.12 and latest Angular CLI, do

```
ng generate service my-service -m app.module
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ng generate service userService

//shorthand for creating service
ng g s serviceName
```

**
When you fire this command it will automatically registered inside providers array.
**

```
providers: [
    UserService
]
```

Answer (score -1):

In Command prompt go to project folder and execute following:

```
ng g s servicename
```

Answer (score -1):

run the below code in Terminal

makesure You are inside your project folder in terminal

```
ng g s servicename --module=app.module
```