# How to generate a service without providing in Angular CLI?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When generating a service using Angular CLI (`ng g s my-service`) it by default provides it in root:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {
...
```

Is there an way to change the setting of the CLI to generate the service without that?

```
@Injectable()
export class MyServiceService {
...
```

**EDIT**

I know I can define a module to provide it with a `--module` flag, I'm asking if:

(1) It is possible not to provide the service at all.

(2) Change the default behavior of the CLI - so it doesn't provide by default, or provide in a module by default (without using the `module` flag) (It behaved differently in earlier versions)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42748773/angular-cli-generate-a-service-and-include-the-provider-in-one-step

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular cli generate a service and include the provider in one step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42748773/angular-cli-generate-a-service-and-include-the-provider-in-one-step)

Comment: It is not configurable in service schematics, see https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/schematics/angular/service/files/__name%40dasherize%40if-flat__/__name%40dasherize__.service.ts

Comment: created feature request https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13335

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `----module` option while creating the service and specify the module where you want to provide the service. For your case to provide in `NgModule` use the following:

`ng g s services/MyService --module=app.module`

Comment: That only answers half my question. See edit for clarification.