# Unknown option -m in angular cli

Tags: angular

I want to create service and register it with `app.module`, but when I run this command

```
ng g s bram -m=app.module
```

I get an error:

> Unknown option: "-m"

[image]

Comment: Remove the "=", remove the ".module"

Answer (score 3):

Generate service doesn’t take a module argument as services don’t really “belong” to a module. To provide in root just open your service and put

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: ‘root’
})
```

[Here are the docs for `service`](https://angular.io/cli/generate#service-command). 
As you can see, service does *not* take a module argument.

Comment: ungh, this is exactly a thing that puts me off when learning new stuff - when tooling gets updated so rapidly that even the community is not able to follow it. but I guess there is a reason for everything. In the current version of angular that I just installed, the above Injectable decorator is inserted by default, so the equivalent of the old -m app.module syntax is to not use it at all. (see Angular 6 answers) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42748773/angular-cli-generate-a-service-and-include-the-provider-in-one-step

Comment: They deprecated it because module level provided services were confusing and had unclear meaning. Services should be root provided if they’re singletons or component provided if not singletons to be clear about which service you’re injecting . In all angular versions, unless lazy loading, there is no difference between a service provided in a feature module or root module in terms of availability or injection. The duplication of module provided services in lazy loaded modules is much more often a bug than intended behavior, so they try to discourage the practice by removing the cli argument.

Answer (score 2):

[image: command tried]Try using

```
ng g s services/bram --module=app.module
```

Comment: but I want to create service  and register it with root module

Comment: not working throwing error Unknown option: '--module'

Comment: @KumarShubham I have tried the same solution. It works fine for me.Have added a screenshot of the same

Comment: @ Seba Cherian :-  I am working in cli version 8.2.1 and node version 10.16.2   and upto "ng g s bram it is working fine"  but not registering with root module, manually it is working but requirement is with cli command

Answer (score 0):

The option --module is not available for a service :
https://angular.io/cli/generate#service

But its available for a componant :
https://angular.io/cli/generate#component