# Angular 2 - No response sending objects to a <router-outlet> component with an Observable service

Tags: angular, observable

I am trying to have a service pass, from a parent component, an object to a child component via a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`. I used the docs to guide me https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service, however when I try to run the app, I receive no error or output.

the service's code:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs';
import {MyObject} from '../models/my-object.model';

@Injectable()
export class ObjectTransferService {
    private myObjectSource = new Subject<MyObject>();
    objectSource$ = this.myObjectSource.asObservable();

    sendMyObject(myObject: MyObject) {
        this.myObjectSource.next(myObject);
    }
 }
```

The parent component:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/component';
import {MyObject} from '../models/my-object.model';
import {ObjectTransferService} from '../service/object-transfer.service';

@Component({
    template: `
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `,
    providers: [ObjectTransferService]
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
    public myObject: MyObject = <MyObject>{ foo: 'bar' };
    constructor(private objectTransferService: ObjectTransferService){}

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        this.objectTransferService.sendMyObject(myObject);
    }
}
```

the child Component that comes through the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/component';
import {MyObject} from '../models/my-object.model';
import {ObjectTransferService} from '../service/object-transfer.service';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class ChildComponent {

    constructor(private objectTransferService: ObjectTransferService){
         objectTransferService.objectSource$.subscribe(
         res => console.log('details', res),
         err => console.log('err' ,err));.
    }
}
```

## Update (Answered)

> Changed `new Subject<MyObject>()` to `new BehaviorSubject<MyObject>(<MyObject>{})`

I believe that the reason this was not receiving a response was that the Subject was not being updated with a new value after I had subscribed to it. Using BehaviorSubject allows the observer to be updated with the most recent value, as explained here, [Angular 2 - Behavior Subject vs Observable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494058/angular-2-behavior-subject-vs-observable).

Comment: Does it work if you use `new BehaviorSubject<MyObject>();` instead of `new Subject<MyObject>();`?

Comment: I assume you don't provide `ObjectTransferService` in `ChildComponent`, right?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Correct, the child does not provide ObjecTransferService.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer and Yes! It works with `new BehaviorSubject<MyObject>();` 
:) thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a timing problem. The event in `ngOnInit()` of `ParentComponent` is emitted before the constructor of `ChildComponent` is executed, therefore the subscription happens too late.

`BehaviorSubject` remembers the last event and and passes it to new subscribers, therefore `ChildComponent` receives an event as soon as the subscription is set up.
Alternatively `ReplaySubject` can be used. `ReplaySubject` doesn't require an initial value.