# Angular >= 2 - Service listening to change in another service

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have service which first goes to get some status and does

`this.changedSource.next(value)` 
changedSource is 'rxjs/Subject'

second service which subscribes to it `this.firstService.changed$.subscribe((value) => this.value = value)`

second service comes in picture later at the stage so I think it misses the first change. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the second service is not subscribed to the observable from the first service at the time it fires, `Subject` is the wrong choice.  If you change it to `BehaviorSubject`, it will replay the current value to all subscribers who join after the observable fired.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked. this also helped http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494058/angular-2-behavior-subject-vs-observable