# How to set Behaviour Subject initial value retrieved from Database?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, eventemitter, behaviorsubject

I pass data from parent to its child components via `BehaviorSubject` as the following approach (I simplified the approach for brevity):

```
const subject = new BehaviorSubject(undefined);

// subscriber A
subject.subscribe((data) => {
    if(data !== undefined)
        ReloadData(data);
    else
         FirstLoadData();
});

subject.next(myDataObtainedFromDatabase);
```

In the parent component, I pass the obtained data to all of the components that are subscribed to the subject. On the other hand, I check the data parameter in order to detect if it is the first load or not. At first load I retrieve data from Database, and later I pass the data to the components.

My question is that,

**1)** by using `BehaviorSubject` (I do not want to use `Subject` only), is there a better way to load the child components here at first load?

**2)** For passing data from Parent to Child, is it better to use `BehaviorSubject` rather than `Input()` property even if the latter seems to be easier to apply?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44574026/angular-4-rxjs-behaviorsubject-usage-in-service?rq=1

Comment: Event emitters are for passing from child to parent, input properties pass from parent to child.

Comment: @AdrianBrand Sorry, you right. I meant `Input()` property :) I updated my question.

Comment: @c69 Thanks. In that page `ReplaySubject(1)` is suggested instead of using `BehaviorSubject(null)`. But I think `BehaviorSubject` has more advantages and for this reson I want to use it. So, should I use it by initial value check? Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You pass objects from parent to child with input properties. On your parent you get the data from the service and put it on an observable property like

```
data$ = this.dataService.getData();
```

and in the view pass the data with the async pipe.

```
<child-component [data]="data$ | async"></child-component>
```

and in the child component have a data input

```
@Input()
data: DataType;
```

Now when the service calls next on the data$ observable it is imagically passed to the child component.

No subscribing and managing subscriptions necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your great explanations. Actually I meant `Input()` property rather than `EventEmitter` and thought to use `Input()` property. So, in this case: **1)** As you said, there is really no need to make things complicated. By looking my scenario, I have a parent dashboard component and 4 child components in it. I get statistics at first load to the parent.  When I add a new record using another component, I pass the new statistics to the parent. By using the approach above I can update all of childs and achieve my goals, is that all true?

Comment: **2)** At first load is OK, but later I will update childs from paren as well, but use SignalR for updating parent. In this case does it mean any sense to update childs as the first scenario? The thinkgs that made me confused is about this issue. Any idea?

Comment: Have a read of my article on a library I wrote called RxCache, it might help you. https://medium.com/@adrianbrand/angular-state-management-with-rxcache-468a865fc3fb

Comment: Thanks a lot, but we avoid using extra library as much as we can (I think to use it in my personal projects). So, in this scene, what do you think about my 2 questions above? regards...