# angular 2 Implement rxjs - IntervalObservable for http call for every a defined interval e.g, 5 secs

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, setinterval

I want make a HTTP request and dynamically update in the UI the value that's being observed!

```
import { IntervalObservable } from 'rxjs/observable/IntervalObservable'; 

@Component({ ... }) export class AppComponent { 
    n: number = 0;
     constructor() { 
        IntervalObservable.create(1000).subscribe(n => this.n = n); 
     } 
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @AJT_82 Here is one more :P

Comment: @AJT_82 you can use your old plunkr ;)

Comment: Just to say, the tagging (@AJT_82) won't work if (in this case) I haven't already commented on question. I just happened to come here ;)

Comment: Yeah i know it's in the hope that AJT_82 might come :P it just takes it as a string :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44809537/2829204. May not use `IntervalObservable`, but the effect is the same

Comment: @AJT_82 any inputs are most welcomed :P

Comment: @RaghavendraSS Well as I have mentioned before rxjs knowledge is still limited :P I think the link you got from CozyAzure looks pretty good to me :)

Comment: @AJT_82 Yeah implemented the same :D I thought of translating what you taught me yesterday :P but that's fine!

Comment: A better implementation would be not to query the server from the client every interval but having the server push the notification to the client using sockets.. i dont know your server side code but this can be done in every laguage .. .NET hav SignalR using NodeJS you have socket.io

Comment: @Mortalus Yeah even i was thinking of the same, like in the app Flipboard (https://flipboard.com/) which pushes notifications to the Frontend!