# How to Use Observables to update displayed data on insert

Tags: angular, ionic2

I decided to ask here I've been looking at google the whole day for an answer but I can't seem to understand on how to implement it. So basically, what I want to do is every time I insert data from a modal once it closes it would auto update the list of its parent view. In the past I would go about this by setting a timeout function upon researching I've stumbled upon `Observables`. Now what I want to know is how I can implement this on my current setup.

Here is my component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, ModalController,FabContainer } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ModalCreateNewDirectoryPage } from '../../pages/modal-create-new-directory/modal-create-new-directory';
import {PopupUploadCsvPage} from '../../pages/popup-upload-csv/popup-upload-csv';
import { BeaconRestApiProvider } from '../../providers/beacon-rest-api/beacon-rest-api';
import {ModalShowPhonebookDirectoryPage} from '../../pages/modal-show-phonebook-directory/modal-show-phonebook-directory';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AsyncPipe } from '@angular/common';

/**
 * Generated class for the PhonebookPage page.
 *
 * See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info
 * on Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

 @Component({
    selector: 'page-phonebook',
    templateUrl: 'phonebook.html',
 })
 export class PhonebookPage {

    items: Array<{title: string, icon:string}>;
    infos:any;
    fileHolder:any;
    choice:boolean;
    contacts:any;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public newDirectoryOpenModal:ModalController, public beaconProvider:BeaconRestApiProvider, public uploadPopupDirectoryModal: ModalController, public showPhoneBookDirectoryModal: ModalController ) {

        this.getPhonebook();
    }

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        console.log('ionViewDidLoad PhonebookPage');
    }

    createNewDirectory(fab: FabContainer){

        console.log('This button creates a new directory');

        const showCreateDirectoryModal = this.newDirectoryOpenModal.create(ModalCreateNewDirectoryPage);

        fab.close();

        showCreateDirectoryModal.present(); 

    }

    uploadNewDirectory(fab: FabContainer){
        const showuploadPopup = this.uploadPopupDirectoryModal.create(PopupUploadCsvPage);

        fab.close();

        showuploadPopup.present(); 

    }


    getPhonebook() {
        this.beaconProvider.getPhoneBookDirectories()
        .then(data => {
            this.infos = data;

        }, (err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }

    phonebookIdentity(phonebook){
        var phonebook_id = phonebook.phonebook_id;
        this.beaconProvider.showPhonebookDirectoryList(phonebook_id)
        .then(data => {


            const showDirectoryList = this.showPhoneBookDirectoryModal.create(ModalShowPhonebookDirectoryPage,{list:data});

            showDirectoryList.present();

        }, (err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }

 }
```

and my modal component.ts which controls the modal form

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, ViewController,LoadingController,ToastController} from 'ionic-angular';
import { FormGroup, FormArray, FormBuilder, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { BeaconRestApiProvider } from '../../providers/beacon-rest-api/beacon-rest-api';

/**
 * Generated class for the ModalCreateNewDirectoryPage page.
 *
 * See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info
 * on Ionic pages and navigation.
 */


 @Component({
    selector: 'page-modal-create-new-directory',
    templateUrl: 'modal-create-new-directory.html',
 })
 export class ModalCreateNewDirectoryPage implements OnInit  {



    public createDirectoryForm: FormGroup;
    //directoryInfo: { phonebook_name: string, number: string, personName: string, age: string, address: string} = { phonebook_name:'', number: '', personName: '', age: '', address:''};

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public newDirectoryView:ViewController, public formBuilder: FormBuilder, public beaconProvider:BeaconRestApiProvider, public pageLoader: LoadingController, public toast : ToastController) {

    }

  /*ngOnInit(){
        this.createDirectoryForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            directoryName:['',Validators.required],
            fields: this.formBuilder.array([
                this.initFormChild(),
            ])

        });
    }*/

    ngOnInit(){
        this.createDirectoryForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            directoryName:['',Validators.required],
            fields:this.formBuilder.array([
                this.initField(),
                ])
        });
    }

    initField() {
        return this.formBuilder.group({
            number:['',Validators.required],
            personName: ['',Validators.required],
            age:['',Validators.required],
            address:['',Validators.required],
        });
    }

    addField() {
        const control = <FormArray>this.createDirectoryForm.controls['fields'];
        control.push(this.initField());
    }

    removeField(i: number) {
        const control = <FormArray>this.createDirectoryForm.controls['fields'];
        control.removeAt(i);
    }

    save(form){
        console.log(form);
        var i;
        var phonebookName = form.controls.directoryName._value;
        var fields_array = [];
        var record_set = [];
        var fields = form.controls.fields.controls;
        phonebookName = {"phonebook_name":phonebookName};
        var address,age,number,personName;
        var directory_header = ['number','name','age','address'];
        record_set.push(directory_header);


        for(i = 0; i < fields.length ; i ++ ){
            if(fields[i]._value.address !=""){
                address = fields[i]._value.address;
            }
            else{
                address = '_';
            }
            if(fields[i]._value.age !=""){
                age = fields[i]._value.age;
            }
            else{
                age = '_';
            }
            if(fields[i]._value.number !=""){
                number = fields[i]._value.number;
            }
            else{
                number = '_';
            }
            if(fields[i]._value.personName !=""){
                personName = fields[i]._value.personName;
            }
            else{
                personName = '_';
            }


            fields_array = [number,personName,age,address];
            record_set.push(fields_array);

            //console.log(i.controls.number._value);
            //console.log(i.controls.personName._value);
        }

        var phonebookdetails_array = record_set;

        this.beaconProvider.getPhonebookId(phonebookName).then((res) => {
            var phonebookId = res;
            var manual_phonebook_array = {"phonebook_id":phonebookId,"phonebook_content":phonebookdetails_array};
            let loadingPage = this.pageLoader.create({
                content: 'Processing your request...',
                showBackdrop:false
            });
            loadingPage.present();

            this.beaconProvider.addPhonebookDirectory(manual_phonebook_array).then((res)=>{
                setTimeout(() => {
                    loadingPage.dismiss();
                    this.toast.create({
                    message: `Phonebook Directory Added`,
                    duration: 3000,
                    position: "top",
                }).present();
                this.closeNewDirectoryModal();
                }, 5000);


            },err=>{
                console.log(err);
            })


        }, (err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });



    }




    ionViewDidLoad() {
        console.log('ionViewDidLoad ModalCreateNewDirectoryPage');
    }

    closeNewDirectoryModal(){
        this.newDirectoryView.dismiss();
    }



}
```

I think this is enough to show what I want to happen but if not let me know.

Comment: It would help people to answer your question if you could provide a _minimal_ code. It looks to me like your code has too much going on that it not relevant to your question. It's also helpful if you create a punker where you reproduce your isolated problem.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović yes I'm trying to create a plunkr for it but I have no Idea how to setup ionic in plunkr

Comment: Based on the scripts I provided its a phonebook directory now the modal acts as the form to allow you to create directories while the list pertains to the list of created directories

Comment: How are you linking the modal to the parent component? HTML? or some other way?

Comment: @PraveenM the initial view is the phone book list when you click on the fab button it opens the modal form for creating a new phonebook directory

Comment: What does your code do when you submit the form? Do you call the `save()` method?

Comment: @PraveenM yup i call the save() method to insert the created phonebook directory

Answer (score 0):

Since you're passing the new directory into a service; you can assign the new directory to a [BehaviourSubject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494058/behaviorsubject-vs-observable/40231605#40231605) in the service, which you can then return as Observable and `subscribe` to it from any component.