# Singleton service - different values for its attributes in multiple components

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular2-template, angular2-services

I want to have a shared state/data between two components (**topic component and topic-detail component**). I decided to use a singleton injectable service (**topic service**) for this.

The behaviour is as follows:
If the user clicks on a row from the table (see pic1), **onSelect** method is called (see pic2), and it sets to **topic service** the selected topic(which is that row).

The **topic service** uses **setSelectedTopic** (see pic3) method to set the data/state for the selected topic/row.

In the **TopicDetailComponent** (see pic5) the **topic service** is injected, and when I try to access in **ngOnInit** method, the attribute **this.topicService.selectedTopic**, I get 'undefined', even though the correct topic is passed to service.

So the problem is when the **topic service** passes **selectedTopic** to **TopicDetailComponent ngOnInit**, the **this.topicService.selectedTopic** is undefined.

Can someone help me with this problem?

Thank you!

P.S. I'm new to Angular 2, so please bear with me :)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should completely remove the providers from topics.component.ts if you want the Service to be a singleton. If you specify the TopicService as a provider it will create a new instance of the service and you will lose the singleton behaviour.

Comment: No problem. Keep it going!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it loose the topic information from setting(`topic component`) to fetching(`topic-detail component`), the variables does not have memory. What you need is `Subject` or `BehaviourSubject` variables.
[BehaviorSubject vs Observable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494058/behaviorsubject-vs-observable)

Comment: If you provide me with an actual code snippet of your service, I'm happy to modify it for you; but I'm not rewriting your screenshot

Comment: that sounds great, but I’m more interested in an explanation rather than the code.

Comment: Anyway, here is the repo: https://github.com/andreicovaciu/courses-app/tree/redesign-topics-add-courses/client/src

Comment: Would you like me to contribute towards your Git or post the answer here?

Comment: I have added a pull request with new changes.