# RX + React setState - avoid “Cannot update during an existing state transition”?

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, observable

**Problem**

```
public componentDidMount() { 

    // after component mounts I want to get updates from RX source
    const that = this;
    SomeExternalObservable.subscribe((value) => {
        that.setState((prev, props) => ({
            currentValue: value
        });
    });

}
```

In some cases, I get warning `Cannot update during an existing state transition” React with Observable`.

I checked SO for answers to that problem, but most of them just suggested to move my code to `componentDidMount`.

**What happens here**

- it's not obvious, but subscription on observable can be executed (it's very likely to) synchronously (see here https://github.com/tc39/proposal-observable/issues/38)
- it's even more likely if an observable has already set value (like BehaviourSubject - see tip here [BehaviorSubject vs Observable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494058/behaviorsubject-vs-observable/46058076#46058076))

The problem occurred as well when using libraries like https://github.com/jayphelps/react-observable-subscribe.

Comment: @simonbuchan Does the problem occur if you use another library which I created https://github.com/mmiszy/react-with-observable ? The difference is, it uses `create-subscription` package from Facebook, which is meant deal with sync and async Observables.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative would be to use props instead of setState.

For managing React state with Rx I prefer to use the [mapPropsStream](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#mappropsstream) recompose helper. It can be a bit confusing if you don't tend to use [HOCs](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html), but it is actually pretty simple.

```
const withSomeExternalValue = mapPropsStream(props$ =>
    Observable.combineLatest(
        props$,
        someExternal$.startWith(null),
        (props, someExternalValue) => ({...props, someExternalValue})
    )
);

const MyEnhancedComponent = withSomeExternalValue(MyComponent);
```

*MyEnhancedComponent* is a new Component type. When it will mount, it will also subscribe to the external Observable. Any emitted value will render the component with the new value as prop.

**Additional explanation and notes**:

- The *props$* is an Observable of props. Any change of a prop will result in a new item emitted for *prop$*
- The returned Observable is a new props Observable that its emitted items will be used to render the enhanced component.
- The *.startWith(null)*, is to make sure the enhanced component will be rendered before the first value of *someExternal$* is emitted. In this case, the *someExternalValue* prop will start with null
- *withSomeExternalValue* HOC can be reused if these external values are needed by another component. *withSomeExternalValue(MyAnotherComponent)*
- The mapPropsStream can be used with other Observable implementation - so it should be configured. Here is how to use it with Rx -

Can be configured globally:

```
import rxjsconfig from 'recompose/rxjsObservableConfig'
setObservableConfig(rxjsconfig)
```

Or by using [mapPropsStreamWithConfig](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#mappropsstreamwithconfig):

```
import rxjsConfig from 'recompose/rxjsObservableConfig'
const mapPropsStream = mapPropsStreamWithConfig(rxjsConfig)
```

Comment: I like approach, but I always considered props as a bespoke external interface of the component. Changing them from inside component seems bit dirty.

Answer (score 1):

> I post the question with the answer as it seems allowed, supported
>   here
>   https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking;
>   spent some time to find the issue and couldn't find similar SO post,
>   so I hope it will help someone.

**Solution**

Because we can't expect the subscription to be triggered asynchronously working solution is to force it, i.e. by using Scheduler:

```
public componentDidMount() { 

    // after component mounts I want to get updates from RX source
    const that = this;
    SomeExternalObservable
        .subscribeOn(Scheduler.asap) // here
        .subscribe((value) => {
            that.setState((prev, props) => ({
                currentValue: value
            });
        });

}
```

**Why**

- `componentDidMount` happens directly after rendering and change to state will cause additional render - which can happen in the same tick (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)
- `setState` should work asynchronously, but doesn't have to; React will decide about it at runtime (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)
- Subscription on Observable by default is synchronous.

**Wrap up question**

Is there `React point of view right way` to fix that issue, different than solution presented?