# Angular5 - Not able to use Object.keys as expected

Tags: angular, object

I am working on an app where I am pulling data from our private git enterprise server.  I have an array of strings for the repos to check, I take that data and combine it with some from a local JSON file to give me a structure like:

```
{ 
  repo1: {},
  repo2: {},
  repo3: {}
}
```

The object comes back exactly like I expect.  The issue is when I want to get a count.  Generally in JS I use Object.keys, but when I do it returns an empty array.  I got around this temporarily by creating a local array and pushing the names into it so I could iterate with ngFor.  The more I dig in, the less sense it makes.  I can use Object.keys on an object literal, or my predefined objects with no problem.  The problem is when I try to use it on this returned object.  I am running the code to get the object in ngOnInit().  When I console.log the object it comes back exactly as expected, but if I change the log to be Object.keys(object) it returns blank.  I thought perhaps it was a timing issue so I wrapped the function in a promise and chained a .then off of it.  Again, the object returned by the promise looks correct, but I cannot use Object.keys on it.  I also tried returning Object.keys(object) instead of the object in the function but it still came back blank.

Is there something I am missing? Is there a more 'Angular' way to handle this?  I've been using Angular for a while but never run into something like this.  Wondering if it's a timing issue or something.

```
tabContentSetup(tabArray) {
const filteredObject = {};
const filteredArray = [];
// For each element in the array, get the repo name
tabArray.forEach((repo) => {
  // Grab all prs for the current repo
  this.gitApiService.getPrs(repo)
    // Subscribe to observable which returns an array of PR objects from the repo
    .subscribe((prObjectArray) => {
      // Iterate over each prObject in prObjectArray
      prObjectArray.forEach((prObject) => {
        // Grab the github user that submitted PR in lowercase
        const prObjectUser = prObject.user.login.toLowerCase();
        // If this PR belongs to a consultant, disregard and return
        if (this.instructorsArray.includes(prObjectUser)) {
          return;
        }
        // If filteredObject does not have the current repo yet, add it as a new object
        if (!filteredObject[repo]) {
          filteredObject[repo] = {
            count: 1,
            cohortsArray: [],  // TODO fix this with Object.keys
            cohorts: {}
          };
          filteredArray.push(repo); // TODO find out why Object.keys isn't working
        } else {
          filteredObject[repo]['count']++; // TODO could be shortened with Object.keys
        }
        if (this.gitHubDict[prObjectUser] === undefined) {
          console.warn('Cannot find: ' + prObjectUser + ' in Cohort JSON files');
          return;
        }
        const assignedCohort = this.gitHubDict[prObjectUser].cohort;
        if (!filteredObject[repo]['cohorts'][assignedCohort]) {
          filteredObject[repo].cohortsArray.push(assignedCohort);
          filteredObject[repo]['cohorts'][assignedCohort] = {
            count: 1,
            prs: []
          };
        } else {
          filteredObject[repo]['cohorts'][assignedCohort].count++;
        }
        filteredObject[repo]['cohorts'][assignedCohort]['prs'].push({
          name: this.gitHubDict[prObjectUser].first + ' ' + this.gitHubDict[prObjectUser].last,
          cohort: assignedCohort,
          git: prObjectUser,
          url: prObject.html_url,
          created_at: prObject.created_at,
          updated_at: prObject.updated_at
        });
        });
    });
});
return Object.keys(filteredObject);
}
```

It's way too long which is why I'm going back and trying to refactor with Object.keys.

Comment: Where is the object coming from initially?

Comment: A function that I run in ngOnInit() that returns the object.

Comment: "returns the object" but what creates _that_ object?

Comment: Is this function a promise, or an observable ? could you edit your post with this function that firstly creates the object ? does not seem like an Angular related issue. you should give us more code

Comment: Please, don't describe the code; this doesn't work. The question should contain all relevant code. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: Updated with code.

Comment: The return does not wait on the subscriber, so `filteredObject` is empty. You should make `filteredObject` an observable and subscribe to it.

Comment: @masterfloda would you mind elaborating on that?  I feel like my issue is not grabbing it in the correct order and observables are fairly new to me as a concept.  Do you happen to have some documentation on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return does not wait on the subscriber, so `filteredObject` is empty. You should make `filteredObject` an Observable (or rather, a Subject) and subscribe to it. This part of your code is executed sequentially on the method call:

```
const filteredObject = {};
const filteredArray = [];
tabArray.forEach((repo) => {
    this.gitApiService.getPrs(repo).subscribe();
}
return Object.keys(filteredObject);
```

the part within the `subscribe()` callback method is executed, when `getPrs()` triggers the `next()` in the returned observable (I guess you return `HttpClient.get()`?). So, on call of `tabContentSetup()`, it will return an empty object, because the HTTP requests are not done yet.

I suggest using a BehaviorSubject (see this answer: [BehaviorSubject vs Observable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494058/behaviorsubject-vs-observable)). Declare the `filteredObject` outside of your function and use it's built in getter `.value` and "setter" `.next()`:

```
// initialize a Subject with an empty object
filteredObjectObservable = new BehaviorSubject({});
// initialize a public variable for the count
repoCount: number;

tabContentSetup(tabArray) {
    tabArray.forEach((repo) => {
        this.gitApiService.getPrs(repo).subscribe((prObjectArray) => {
              // set the variable here and use the built in getter, to get the current value
              let filteredObject = this.filteredObjectObservable.value;
              // do your stuff

              // at the very end of the subscribe callback, set the new value. This will also trigger all subscribers
              this.filteredObjectObservable.next(filteredObject);
        }
    }
    // subscribe to the BehaviorSubject (this could also be in the component's OnInit method or anywhere else).
    this.filteredObjectObservable.subscribe((value) => {
        // triggers each time the Subject's next() method is called
        this.repoCount = Object.keys(value).length;
    }
}
```

Note: Code is untested :-)