# Handle Error through Observable Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

On a service in Angular, in the following api call, what is the way to catch an error:

```
getData(sourceId: string): Observable <Array<CustomObject>> {
    const obs: BehaviorSubject<Array<CustomObject>> = this.servicesObsCache[sourceId];
    const options = new RequestOptions({...});
    this.http
        .get(API_URL + 'sourceId' + '/serviceendpoint', options, true)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .first()
        .subscribe(
            body => {
                ...
                obs.next(services);
            },
            err => {
                obs.next(err); // Is this statement allowed on error?
                obs.error(err);
            }
        );
    return obs.filter((results) => !!results);
}
```

I have tried to use `obs.next(err);` but I believe it doesn't catches the error when **api fails** and instead takes it as *success*.

What should I use so as to allow the method which invokes the `getData(<custom_id>)`, catch the error?

Comment: you can throw the `error` as `return Observable.throw(err);` and then catch it where you are calling `getData(<id>)`

Comment: What do you mean by "catch"? For example be able to print the error or want to turn it into `next` or what?

Comment: @martin Similar to `next` as I am able to get the error object, but the console logs as *Uncaught*. The `next()` treats it as success itself. So I guess, it is not advisable.

Comment: @AnshumanJaiswal Ideally `Observable.throw(err);` should work 
 but unfortunately it didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I researched the [difference between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494058/behaviorsubject-vs-observable) `BehaviorSubject` and `Observable` and found that the former is *stateful* while the latter one is *stateless*.

I inspected my code and found that, since I was using `BehaviorSubject`, on error, being it stateful, it always contained the error obect. Due to which, when I tried to execute the following code before making the api call:

```
obs.getValue();
```

it returned the error by breaks the ideal flow and prevented from making the service call.

As a result, I used `Observable` as below:

```
getData(sourceId: string): Observable<Array<CustomObject>> {
    return Observable.create(obs => {
        const options = new RequestOptions({ ...});
        this.http
            .get(API_URL + 'sourceId' + '/serviceendpoint', options, true)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .first()
            .subscribe(
                body => {
                ...
                obs.next(services);
            },
            err => obs.error(err);
        );
    });
}
```

Using this, the error gets handled by `Observable` error handling through its subscription.

Also, the following code should not be used in error handling:

```
obs.next(err);
```

although, it sends the required error object to the calling service, but it does so on success and not on error. In short, it is *not a good* practice to catch the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
You have to catch http error before subscription like the following.
this.http.get(url).map((response) => response).catch((e) => {
   //Catching based on http error code.
   if(e.status == 400){
   //Do anything based on http status code.
}

//Throw Custom error message.
return Observable.throw(new Error(`${ e.status } ${ e.statusText }`));
});
```

Comment: It didn't returned the error where I have called the service.