# Angular Observable not updating content

Tags: angular, observable, angular2-forms

I have two components and a service in angular 4, the component one add a contact and the component two shows the contacts. I'm using HttpClient and Observables to get all the contacts, but when I add one contact my second component is not updating the contacts. I do it all this stuff through a service.The contacts displays well on start but they are not updating when I fire add() function.

**My contact.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class ContactService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private messageService: MessageService) { }

  private contactsUrl = 'api/contacts';

  getContacts(): Observable<Contact[]> {
      return this.http.get<Contact[]>(this.contactsUrl)
        .pipe(
            tap(contacts => this.log(`Fetched contacts`)),
            catchError(this.handleError('getContacts', []))
        );
  }


  getContact(id: number): Observable<Contact> {
      const url = `${this.contactsUrl}/${id}`;
      return this.http.get<Contact>(url).pipe(
      tap(_ => this.log(`fetched contact id=${id}`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<Contact>(`getContact id=${id}`))
    );
  }

  addContact (contact: Contact): Observable<Contact> {
      return this.http.post<Contact>(this.contactsUrl, contact, httpOptions).pipe(
          tap((contact: Contact) => this.log(`${contact.name} added to list`)),
          catchError(this.handleError<Contact>('addContact'))
      );

  }

}
```

**My contact-item.component.ts**

```
   export class ContactItemComponent implements OnInit {

  contacts: Contact[] = [];

  constructor(private contactService: ContactService) { }


  ngOnInit(){
      console.log("init");
      this.getContacts();
  }

  getContacts(): void {
      this.contactService.getContacts().subscribe(contacts => this.contacts = contacts);
  }

}
```

**My contact-add.component.ts**

```
export class ContactAddComponent {

  contacts: Contact[] = [];

  constructor(private contactService: ContactService) { }
 add(name: string, surname: string, phoneNumber: number): void {
      name = name.trim();
      surname = surname.trim();
      phoneNumber = phoneNumber;

      if(!name || !surname || !phoneNumber) { return; }
      this.contactService.addContact({ name, surname, phoneNumber } as Contact)
        .subscribe(contact => {
            this.contacts.push(contact);
        })
  }
```

Comment: Your `contact-item.component` has no way of knowing when a contact has been added...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sergio, when you add a "contact", you make: 1) add the contact in dbs, 2.-add the contact to the array contact in the contact-add.component, nothing else. You must do "something more" to contact-item.component take acount the change.

When we subscribe to contactService.getContact() ONLY make "getContact" one time.

Solutions:

1.- the service store the contact, and we use a getter to get/set the values
In your contactService

```
@Injectable()
export class ContactService {

  contacts: Contact[];  //declare a variable contacts
  private contactsUrl = 'api/contacts';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private messageService: MessageService) { }

  getContacts(): Observable<Contact[]> {
      if (this.contacts)   //If yet exist, simply
          return Observable.of(this.contacts);

      return this.http.get<Contact[]>(this.contactsUrl)
        .pipe(
            tap(contacts =>{
                this.log(`Fetched contacts`)
            }),
            catchError(this.handleError('getContacts', []))
        );
  }

  getContact(id: number): Observable<Contact> {
     ...
  }

  addContact (contact: Contact): Observable<Contact> {
      ...    
  }

}
```

Then, you can have in your contact-items.component

```
  export class ContactItemComponent implements OnInit {
  //contacts is a "getter", not a variable
  get contacts(){
        return this.contactService.contacts;
  }
  set contacts(value)
  {
      this.contactService.contacts=value;
  }
  constructor(private contactService: ContactService) { }

  ngOnInit(){
      this.getContacts();
  }

  getContacts(): void {
      this.contactService.getContacts().subscribe((contacts)=>{
           //see that really you're changing this.contactService.contacts
            this.contacts=contacts;
      })
  }
```

And in your ContactAdd-component

```
export class ContactAddComponent {
      //yes, in your contactAddComponent you have a getter
      //contacts is a "getter", not a variable
      get contacts(){
            return this.contactService.contacts;
      }
      set contacts(value)
      {
          this.contactService.contacts=value;
      }

  constructor(private contactService: ContactService) { }
 add(name: string, surname: string, phoneNumber: number): void {
      name = name.trim();
      surname = surname.trim();
      phoneNumber = phoneNumber;

      if(!name || !surname || !phoneNumber) { return; }
      this.contactService.addContact({ name, surname, phoneNumber } as Contact)
        .subscribe(contact => {
            //really you push contact of your contactService.contact
            this.contacts.push(contact);
        })
  }
```

2.-Make a subscribe to a Observable in your service as Andrey indicate you.

Your service

```
@Injectable()
export class ContactService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private messageService: MessageService) { }
  //declara a Subject
  private contactsSource = new Subject<Contact>();

  // Declare a observable
  contactsObservable = this.contactsSource.asObservable();

  private contactsUrl = 'api/contacts';

  getContacts(): Observable<Contact[]> {
     ...
  }
  getContact(id: number): Observable<Contact> {
      ...
  }

  addContact (contact: Contact): Observable<Contact> {
      return this.http.post<Contact>(this.contactsUrl, contact, httpOptions).pipe(
          tap((contact: Contact) => {
              this.log(`${contact.name} added to list`)
              this.contactSource.next(contact) //<--say that contactObservable "change"
            }),
          catchError(this.handleError<Contact>('addContact'))
      );
  }
}
```

then, your contacts-item.component subcribe the observable

```
export class ContactItemComponent implements OnInit {

  contacts: Contact[] = [];

  constructor(private contactService: ContactService) { }


  ngOnInit(){
      console.log("init");
      this.getContacts();
      this.subscribeChange();
  }

  getContacts(): void {
      this.contactService.getContacts().subscribe(contacts => this.contacts = contacts);
  }
  subscribeChange():void{
      this.contactService.contactsObservable.subscribe(
            contact=> this.contact.push(contact))
  }
}
```

As you can see, http.get is a "special observable" that have NOT a "next" to change

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to communicate one component with other.
The solution can be to use BehaviorSubject. Here is an example [BehaviorSubject vs Observable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494058/behaviorsubject-vs-observable)

**ContactService**

1) You need to create BehaviorSubject that will keep the last value of contacts.

```
    private contacts: BehaviorSubject<Contact[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Contact[]>([]);
```

2) If need to add new value to contacts, need to call **next method** with updated contacts on BehaviorSubject object.

```
    this.contacts.next(updatedContacts);
```

3) In **ContactItemComponent** you need to subscribe on BehaviorSubject contacts. And when next method is called you will get updated contacts

Answer (score -1):

You need to emit event from your contact-add.component.ts so your contact-item.component.ts can fire getContacts() to receive new updatet list of contacts.

More on components interaction you can find [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)