# How do I minimize XHR requests with ngrx when the same object is requested concurrently by multiple Angular components?

Tags: angular, ngrx

Say I have an angular component that displays a list of items:

```html
<app-item *ngFor="let item of items"></app-item>
```

Say that an `item` looks like this:

```
interface Item {
  userId: number;
  name: string;
}
```

and `ItemComponent` wants to display an item with the following HTML:

```html
<p>{{username$ | async}} has item "{{item.name}}"</p>
```

And in the component's typescript file, these are the relevant parts:

```
@Input() item: Item;

username$: Observable<string>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.store.dispatch(new LoadUser({id: item.userId}));

  this.username$ = this.store$.select(selectUser, {id: item.userId}).pipe(
    filter(user => !!user),
    map(user => username)
  );
}
```

Now, if I have lots of items by the same user, every time an `<app-item>` is rendered, that will trigger a new API call to get the user (via the dispatched action and relative effect, omitted for brevity), even if the user is already in the store.

To obviate this, I modified my effect to first check if a user in the store, and if it, return it, otherwise fetch a new one from the API.

But this only works for requests that are happening later in time: in the scenario above, they all start at about the same time (before the first API request returns a value), so they are all run via the API.

I feel like this would be a common problem... what is the proper way to deal with it?

Thanks!

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50864978/angular-rxjs-6-how-to-prevent-duplicate-http-requests) SO question.

Answer (score 0):

[Use the `exhaustMap` operator](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/exhaustMap).
This will cancel incoming requests when there's one pending.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `shareReplay()` in your service file where the HTTP call is being made. With that, you can share your observable response.

```js
import { shareReplay } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class AService {
  getUsers(id: number): Observable<SomeInterface> {
     return this.http.get<SomeInterface>(`url/${id}`).pipe( 
       shareReplay()
     )
  }
}
```