# AWS amplify auth.completeNewPassword() doesn' work

Tags: angular, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I am updating password using `auth.completeNewPassword()` . When I  try to update the password. I get this error.

```
TypeError: user.completeNewPasswordChallenge is not a function
    at Auth.js:865
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (zone-evergreen.js:960)
    at AuthClass.push../node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/Auth.js.AuthClass.completeNewPassword (Auth.js:864)
    at AuthenticationService.updatePassword (authentication.service.ts:68)
    at CompletePasswordComponent.onSubmit (complete-password.component.ts:30)
    at CompletePasswordComponent_Template_form_ngSubmit_1_listener (complete-password.component.html:2)
    at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.js:21806)
    at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.js:21848)
    at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (core.js:37171)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
```

Here is the code I am using:

```js
    Auth.completeNewPassword(user, password, []).then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch((err) =>  console.log(err));
```

To pass the first parameter(user), I am storing cognito user in local storage and retrieving when I need to use this method.

Comment: Im just gussing that you need also AWS package install.

Comment: @Talg123 What packages are you suggesting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue using RxJS BehaviorSubject.

I answered this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63354762/11874525).