# Get value from Observable before re-execution

Tags: javascript, angular, service, observable

Im currently getting the new updated user value this way:

```
 this.Service.user$.subscribe(data => {
      this.userData = data;
      this.userId = data._id;
    });
```

but the updateUser is only executed every 5 secs.

So before its loaded the `userData` and `UserId` is empty.

is there a way i can get the stored user data from whats already in the service, instead of waiting 5 secs to it beeing executed again?

something like:

```
 this.Service.user$().GET((data:any) => { // gets the value already stored

    });
```

*How would i accomplish this?*

Service code:

```
     user$: Observable<any>;


  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {
    this.user$ = this.userChangeSet.asObservable();
  }



  updateUser(object) {
    this.userChangeSet.next(object);
  }
```

Edit:

Also, how would i destory all subscribes on `ngOnDestroy` event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do in your service is internally use a BehaviourSubject to 
store the values but expose this as an Observable.

Here is a quote from the docs detailing what a BehaviourSubject is

> One of the variants of Subjects is the BehaviorSubject, which has a notion of "the current value".
>   It stores the latest value emitted to its consumers, and 
>   whenever a new Observer subscribes, it will immediately receive the "current value" from the BehaviorSubject

See [here](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#behaviorsubject) for more.

Service code:

```js
private _user$ = new BehaviourSubject<any>(null); // initially null

constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {
  this.userChangeSet.subscribe(val => this._user$.next(val))
}

get user$ () {
  return this._user$.asObservable();
}
```

Then you can use it like normal in your component.

```js
this.service.user$.subscribe(v => {
  // do stuff here
})
```

Note that the first value
that the component will get will be null since this is the inital value of
the BehaviourSubject.

**EDIT:**

In the component

```js
private _destroyed$ = new Subject();

public ngOnDestroy (): void {
    this._destroyed$.next();
    this._destroyed$.complete();
}
```

And then for the subscription

```js
this.service.user$.pipe(
  takeUntil(this._destroyed$)
).subscribe(v => {
  // do stuff here
})
```

The way this works is that when the destroyed$ subject emits, the observables that have piped `takeUntil(this._destroyed$)` will unsubscribe from their respective sources.

Comment: How would i destroy the subscribe when leaving component?

Comment: A good way is to use  `takeUntil`. Check out **6) Clean up subscriptions** [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/best-practices-for-a-clean-and-performant-angular-application-288e7b39eb6f)

Comment: is there some kind of tslint i need to update? get an error: http://prntscr.com/n06edf

Comment: ERROR in src/app/global.service.ts(18,33): error TS1005: ';' expected.

Comment: My initialisation was incorrect, should be `private _user$ = new BehaviourSubject<any>(null)`. Have updated the answer!

Comment: still getting: http://prntscr.com/n0e5xf

you never mentioned how userChangeSet variable should be? currently its:

  private userChangeSet = new Subject<any>();

Comment: That `.user.subscribe` should work. If `userChangeSet` is a subject you should be able to subscribe to it and call `.next()` as you detailed in your question.

Comment: i dont understand why it wont work with me properly... code: http://notes.io/5nTS

Comment: Did you remember to add the `get user$ () {
  return this._user$.asObservable();
}` to the `GlobalService`

Comment: i edited to:     user$ = this._user$.asObservable();
 and then it seems to work .

Comment: Good to hear its fixed :)

Answer (score 1):

Use BehaviorSubject for userChangeSet. It emits value immediately upon subscription.
Example:

```
userChangeSet = new BehaviorSubject<any>(this.currentData);
```

Comment: Could you give me a full working sample, so i could understand it more? :)

Comment: Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494058/behaviorsubject-vs-observable)

Comment: Thanks, updated topic with one more question regarding destroy.