# Can't access a variable data and cannot return it in Angular Firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular7

My code for accessing a document from firestore is as below.

```
let data;
this.firestore.collection('groups').doc(tempId).ref.get().then(function(doc) {
  if (doc.exists) {
      data = doc.data();
      console.log("Document data:", doc.data());   // Gives correct data here
  } else {
      console.log("No such document!");
  }
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
console.log("Service Data :: " + data); //It says undefined here.
```

Here, I want to return the data of **doc.data()** to another component. But, In the **console.log("Service Data :: " + data);** it says undefined.

So, I'm confused like why data variable does not has the value of **doc.data()** in it.

Comment: Ok. Sorry. Took back my aswer. I was unable to test my code today, so sorry. Will get back with a tested solution, but it will rely on `valueChanges()` and observables rather than Promises, if that's ok.

Comment: I'm fine with it as far as code works

Answer (score 2):

This might be the reason , where **second console** statement is executing before **first**. Thread based execution will make the request to your **`firestore`** and it will not wait for the response where as it will executes other lines of code. So your second console is executing before the first.

```
let data;
this.firestore.collection('groups').doc(tempId).ref.get().then(function(doc) {
  if (doc.exists) {
      data = doc.data();
      console.log("Document data:", doc.data());   // first console
  } else {
      console.log("No such document!");
  }
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
console.log("Service Data :: " + data); //second console
```

If you want to change this behavior try call your second console next to the first one.

> If you want pass the data to other component use [BehaviourSubject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494058/behaviorsubject-vs-observable)

```
  public  dataSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);

  this.dataSource.next(doc.data()); 
  console.log("Document data:", doc.data());   // first console
```

Try to pass `dataSource` object to your other component with help of service  class. follow this link for more info about [angular-behaviorsubject-service](https://medium.com/@weswhite/angular-behaviorsubject-service-60485ef064fc)

**second Component.ts**

```
constructor(private service: Commonservice) { }

someMethod() {
  this.service.dataSource.subscribe((response: any) =>{
    // do something with data
  })
}
```

Comment: oh I see. But What should I do if I want to pass the data to another component?

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry but I'm new to this so would you please help me with the code how can I achieve that? I tried to understand the link but cannot compare it with my requirements.

Comment: @Virus i have updated my answer check it once. I hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: I tried but got error like "Error getting document: TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataSource' of undefined". Moreover when I subscribe How I get the data there mean in which variable?

Answer (score 1):

the `.get()` method returns a promise, which is executed asynchronously once you call `.then()`. Because of this, the next line that gets executed is 
`console.log("Service Data :: " + data);`. Javascript does not wait for the promise to be resolved and instead just carries on with the next synchronous line which is the second console.

The way I usually go about this is passing the whole promise to the other component or better yet, I use the `.valueChanges()` of the `.doc()` which returns an observable, and use the async pipe in the component I'm passing to:

```
// Get Observable on document. Returns Observable<any>
const group$ = this.firestore.doc('/groups' + tempId).valueChanges();
```

You then have two options:

1. Use `group$.subscribe();`
2. Pass `group$`to the component you want and use the async pipe there

First option:

```
// In your component:
let data;
group$.subscribe(doc => {
  if (doc.exists) {
    data = doc
    console.log("Document data:", doc);   // No need to call data().
  } else {
    console.log("No such document!");
  },
  error => console.log("Error getting document:", error);
)
```

Second option, passing into the component where you would like the observable to be evaluated and the data displayed:

```
<div *ngIf="group$ | async as doc">
  Your html here {{ doc.someProperty }} further html here...
</div>
```

Personally, I prefer the second choice because it goes along with the framework nicely and keeps me from making asynchronous errors.

Have a look at angularfire2's Github repo for docs [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md). If there is no need to evaluate the observable by hand in code, I would not do this and let the framework handle it.

One final thing: If you use the observable and want to do some error handling when using the async pipe, you probably want to do so when creating the observable:

```
// Get Observable on document. Returns Observable<any>
// In error case, returns Observable of the error string
const group$ = this.firestore.doc('/groups' + tempId).valueChanges()
  .pipe(
    catchError(error => of(`Error getting document: ${error}`))
  );
```

Comment: ok so I tried according to your comments and it gave me an error in console like "Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined"

Comment: or How can I use async pipe in another component?

Comment: Actually the code you provided is in one method get(id: string) so what should I return in this method? and How to use this method in another component to get the data.

Comment: Sorry, had to update my code. See above. For passing, you define an @Input() variable in your other component and use the observable in your template ( e. g. <ng-template *ngIf="group$ | async as group">...content<ng-template>

Comment: In Updated code it gives error like "Property 'then' does not exist on type 'Observable<DocumentSnapshot>"

Comment: I did a major edit. Should work like this. I would not use the get operator at all since you miss the realtime part of firestore that way.