# Angular: cdkVirtualFor not rendering new items

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, virtualscroll

I'm building a vertically scrolling calendar. I'm getting the initial days to load, but when new days are added to the list, they aren't being rendered.

```
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport
  class="demo-viewport"
  [itemSize]="100"
  (onContentScrolled)="handleScrollChange($event)"
>
  <calendar-day
    *cdkVirtualFor="let day of days; trackBy: trackByFn"
    [day]="day"
  ></calendar-day>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
<button (click)="goToToday()">go</button>
```

I have a service with a `BehaviorSubject` updating the days. I know the list of days is being updated, but the change doesn't seem to be detected.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this._daysService.days$.subscribe(days => {
      this.days = days;
    })
    this.watchScroll();
    this.handleScrollingUp();
    this.handleScrollingDown();
  }
```

For more info, the StackBlitz repo is public https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-infinite-calendar

Comment: Try to use `async` pipe to subscribe to an observable. Maybe this would help. Also, I'm not sure about rightfulness of making `this.days = days` since it would make a reference instead of copying an array. I've been having some problems due to JavaScript nature and was forced to use `lodash` to make deep copies of arrays and objects

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured this out.

Originally, I was adding new days by grabbing the current value like this

```
let items = this.items$.value;
items.push(newItem);
this.items$.next(items)
```

Apparently, this is actually a mutation of the value of the `BehaviorSubject`'s value, therefore not creating a new array to return and not triggering change detection.

I changed it to

```
let items = [...this.items$.value];
items.push(newItem);
this.items$.next(items)
```

and all is good.

So, although the answers here are correct in that I was mutating the original array, the information I needed was **calling `next()` with a mutated version `BehaviorSubject`'s current value does not emit a *new* array. An `emit` event does not guarantee immutability.**

Comment: You probably just saved me hours! I was on the same train of thought thinking that by firing a new emission of next, it would be a new object.

Answer (score 17):

The `*cdkVirtualFor` would only be updated if you update it immutably i.e. you cannot update the array after it is initialized. We use the spread operator to get what you are looking for.

Check this very simple [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-efdcyc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)... here i have used 2 methods which you can try and see:

- `addCountryOld` method mutates the array by pushing an object to our array and hence the rendered view is not updated.
- `addCountryNew` method uses immutability through the spread operator which results in the rendered view getting updated.

This is the code for **addCountryNew**:

```
addCountryNew(){
    let  newObj = {'name':'stack overflow country', "code":'SO'};
    this.myList = [...this.myList, newObj];
  }
```

Comment: I understand this, but I’m not sure why it is considered mutation when I’m setting days = the new value that comes through from the BehaviorSubject. I’m not mutating, I’m replacing this.days every time the BehaviorSubject changes.

Comment: From what I understand, once an array is initialized, it can't change, when you assign a new value, you change it and hence mutation occurs...

Comment: Yep. That’s what mutation is, but I’m not doing that. I’m reassigning the array to the value emitted by the BehaviorSubject. If I’m wrong about that, I’d sure like to know why.

Comment: Yes you're reassigning, but you're assigning the same reference again, so it's not actually changing anything.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

```
this.days = days;
```

do

```
this.days = [...days];
```

Works.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-infinite-calendar-amcapx?file=src/app/calendar/calendar.component.ts

Answer (score 2):

I had a strange behavior with `*cdkVirtualFor` where it would not update even if I set the variable immutably as described in most of the answers above.

In my scenario if would not render the items when updated from an empty array to a non-empty array.

After spending a lot of time my last restore was to wrap `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport` with an `ng-container` based on the existence of items.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="items.length">
      <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
          <div *cdkVirtualFor="let item of items">
          ...
          </div>
      </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
</ng-container>
```

This way the entire container was re-initialized when items became available. This solved my issue.

Comment: This did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done like this:

You can initialise another variable as observale of your behaviorsubject "days$".

in calendar-days.service.ts

```
  public days$: BehaviorSubject<Date[]>;
  public dayObs$: Observable<Date[]>

  constructor() {
    this.days$ = new BehaviorSubject<Date[]>(this._initialDays);
    this.dayObs$ = this.days$.asObservable();
  }
```

And then subscribe that observable in calender.component.ts inside ngOnInit like this:

```
this._daysService.dayObs$.subscribe(days => {
  this.days = days;
})
```

Comment: There shouldn’t be a need for multiple variables. A BehviorSubject is an observable with some special qualities (mainly that it emits its current value on subscription).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494058/behaviorsubject-vs-observable