# Angular virtual scroll: prepend new items when new data streams in with Microsoft SignalR

Tags: javascript, angular, signalr, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

Currently I'm using Microsoft SignalR for live updates on my data and whenever new data comes in, I would like it to be added to the existing virtual list while removing that entry from where it was.

Essentially how do you unshift with virtual scroll and splice out that data entry without having to reload the list.

Comment: [...DATA,NEWENTRY]

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. please add code snippet and technical details about the ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for not being detailed enough but found the answer to my question here: [cdkVirtualFor not rendering new items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55369253/cdkvirtualfor-not-rendering-new-items)