# Add an Item to a cdkVirtualFor

Tags: angular, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

I am using a cdkVirtualFor due to a large number of users in my list. The list has filtering on it and it works much better when it is a cdkVirtualFor rather than a regular *ngFor.

I now need to add items to the list using

```
this.filteredUsersList.unshift({});
```

When I use

```
<div *ngFor="let user of filteredUserList">
 <div>Each Item</div>
</div>
```

The new empty item shows at the top of my list.

When I use

```
<div *cdkVirtualFor="let user of filteredUserList">
  <div>Each Item</div>
</div>
```

The item does not appear.

I want to continue using cdkVirtualFor. How I can I make the changes to the underlying object show?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here. [cdkVirtualFor not rendering new items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55369253/cdkvirtualfor-not-rendering-new-items). Basically cdkVirtualFor wants changes to the underlying array the array to be immutable. Using the spread operator instead of unshift did the trick.

```
let newUser = {}
this.filteredUserNames = [newUser, ...this.filteredUserNames]
```