# Subject subscribe is not triggering

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular7, subject

I want to pass the data from one component to another component using Subject. I am using Angular 7.
Below is my service: -

```
public shareData = new Subject();
setShareDataOfReadingDetail(datatobeShared:any){
    console.log(datatobeShared)
    this.shareData.next(datatobeShared);
    this.shareData.complete()

  }

  getShareDataOfReadingDetail(){

    return this.shareData.asObservable();
  }
```

My first component is : -

```
shareDetail(detail){
    this.readingService.setShareDataOfReadingDetail(detail)
    this.router.navigate(['./tabs/tabs/readings/detail'])
  }
```

And the component in which I am getting the data is : -

```
  ngOnInit() {

    this.readingService.getShareDataOfReadingDetail().subscribe((data)=>{console.log(data)})

  }
```

But the subscribe for subject is not triggering at all (i.e it is not printing anything in the console)

Comment: You immediately `complete()` your `Subject` in `setShareDataOfReadingDetail()`. If I remember correctly, you need to use a [`BehaviorSubject`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494058/behaviorsubject-vs-observable) instead to replay your last value.

Comment: @alexkucksdorf I have used BehaviourSubject also. It is also not triggering

Comment: @alexkucksdorf It worked fine using BehaviourSubject and removing complete sentence. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

When do you instantiate the second component? Before or after the call to shareDetail? I'm assuming it is as a result of the router navigation. If so, you are sending a value and completing the Subject before the details component gets a chance to subscribe to it. I would hold off completion of the Subject until later, probably in the ngOnDestroy of the service.

I would also consider using a BehaviorSubject or a ReplaySubject, as well (to provide caching of the value).

Comment: I am instantiating the same in shareDetail only.