# BehaviorSubject firing twice

Tags: rxjs, angular7

Im using BehaviourSubject from RxJS:

```ts
private rights = new BehaviorSubject<Array<string>>([]);


updateRights(rights: Array<string>) {
  this.rights.next(rights);
}

getRights(): Observable<any> {
  return this.rights.asObservable();
}
```

I'm updating the rights in the root component and im subscribing to it in another component like:

```ts
 this.configService.getRights().subscribe(res => {
   console.log(res);
 })
```

This subscription is firing twice. Once when the data is empty and then again when the data is received.

I want the subscription to fire only once and get only the latest data. What should be done?

Answer (score 8):

[BehaviourSubject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/subjects/behaviorsubject.html) emits the value on subscription by default, and it is intended design. If you do not want this behaviour, use [Subject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/subjects/subject.html) instead.

Comment: This is the correct answer. When using rxjs, its very important to know the difference between Subject, BehaviorSubject and ReplaySubject (ReplaySubject isnt used that much, usually you will use Subject or BehaviorSubject).

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

```
private currnetRightsSubject: BehaviorSubject<string[]>;
public currentRights: Observable<string[]>;

constructor() {
    this.currnetRightsSubject= new BehaviorSubject<string[]>(/*.......*/);
    this.currentRights= this.currnetRightsSubject.asObservable();
}

public get currentRightsValue(){
    return this.currnetRightsSubject.value;
}
```

**updated**

fill the `BehaviorSubject` like this:

```
this.currnetRightsSubject.next(someValue);
```

Comment: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Observable<string[]>'

Comment: tried it. Now it doesnt wait for value.its showing empty array

Comment: you must put value in behaviorSubject first, i update the answer

Comment: check my question ..i am doing this in the updateRights function

Comment: i removed .value from get current rights value function ..and the behaviour subject returns.the problem is getting the valuefrom it .value doesnt work

Comment: its wrong, you put rights inside rights again, just provide some string for BS

Comment: i want to push array to the behaviour subject not string

Comment: Array of strings

Comment: the thing is only triggereing once but its before the value is received.. im updating rights in the root component,but the behaviour subject doesnt wait for the updation

Comment: see this [BehaviorSubject vs Observable?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40231605/2126355)

Comment: ya.ok ..the problem with using subects is that im not able to wait for the response

Comment: i resolved it using take operator from rxjs using the same behaviour subject as in my question