# Get undefined when using subject to share data between components

Tags: angular, subject

I am trynig to send data from one component to another but it gives me undefined always !

This is my services.ts :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

 @Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
 })
export class DataService {

 constructor() { }

private subjectDossierNumber = new Subject<any>();

sendDossierNumber( dossierNumber : string){
  this.subjectDossierNumber.next(dossierNumber);
}

getDossierNumber() : Observable<any>{
 return this.subjectDossierNumber.asObservable();
}
}
```

This is the component which send data :

```
 dossierNumber:string;
 constructor(private dataService : DataService){}
 ngOnInit(){
   this.dossierNumber="2145"}
  createNewRequest() { this.dataService.sendDossierNumber(this.dossierNumber); }
```

And This is the component which receive data :

```
dossierNumber : string;
constructor(private dataService : DataService){}
ngOnInit() { 
  this.dataService.getDossierNumber().subscribe(data => {this.dossierNumber = data;})
  }
```

It is going well in the sendDossierNumber() method but in the getDossierNumber() method the data is always undefined. Can anyone know what is the problem please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guess is that you are using a `Subject`, and not a `BehaviorSubject`. The main difference is that a `Subject` does not return the initial value when you start subscribing to it, but a `BehaviorSubject` does.

**With a Subject**

- If you start subscribing, and then send a new message, the message will be received.
- If you send a message, and start subscribing afterwards, you will not get the current state (value) of the `Subject`.

**With a BehaviorSubject**

- If you start subscribing, and then send a new message, the message will be received.
- If you send a message, and start subscribing afterwards, you will get the current state (value) of the `BehaviorSubject`.

Here are some useful questions for further reading:

- [Difference between Subject and BehaviorSubject](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39494058/1471485)
- [Difference between Observable and BehaviorSubject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494058/behaviorsubject-vs-observable)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `private subjectDossierNumber = new BehaviorSubject<string>('')`. Consider `ReplaySubject` if you want the subject to hold more than one value.