# Cross Component communication using emit and subscribe not working

Tags: angular, angular8

I want to use Event emitter and subscribe in parent component.

This is my Service Code

```
@Injectable()
export class RecipeService{
    recipeselected= new EventEmitter<string>() ;
}
```

This is code, where I have used, event Emitter.

The function onselected is working

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-receipie-item',
  templateUrl: './receipie-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./receipie-item.component.css'],
  providers:[RecipeService]
})
export class ReceipieItemComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() recipe:ReceipieModel ;//custom property
 
  constructor(private recipeservice:RecipeService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onselected(){
    this.recipeservice.recipeselected.emit("hello");
    // console.log('hello');
  }  

}
```

This is code, where I have used, subscribe to event.

The problem is it is not working in subscribe.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-receipies',
  templateUrl: './receipies.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./receipies.component.css'],
  providers:[RecipeService]
})
export class ReceipiesComponent implements OnInit {
  selectedrecipe:ReceipieModel;
  constructor(private recipeservice:RecipeService) { 

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.recipeservice.recipeselected.subscribe(
      recipe=>{ 
        console.log(recipe);
      }
    );
  }

  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up things.

Either use the Service to define an Observable like this:

```
  private _subject$: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();

  get subject$(): Subject<string> {
    return this._subject$;
  }

  // emit new data
  this.yourService.subject$.next('new data');
```

Then, in the component where you want to receive the data:

```
this.yourService.subject$.subscribe(data => { console.log(data) }
```

or using EventEmitter

```
  // componentA.ts
  @Output() public onDataChanged: EventEmitter<Array<EventItem>> = new EventEmitter();

  // publish new data
  public dataChanged() {
    this.onDataChanged.emit('new data')
  }

  // any other component, using your 'app-componentA'
  <app-componentA
      (dataChanged)="receivingMethod($event)">
  </app-componentA>
```

Here is some literature:

[BehaviorSubject vs Observable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494058/behaviorsubject-vs-observable)

https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter

Answer (score 1):

Is there any specific reason to use [`EventEmitter`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/11.2.11/packages/core/src/event_emitter.ts#L105) in the service? `EventEmitter` is an Angular specific extension of RxJS `Subject` and are intended to be used with `@Output` decorator for data sharing b/n sibling components. Subscribers to RxJS `Subject` would only receive notifications that are emitted *after* the subscription.

If the components are unrelated, and if you wish to fetch an emission *in the future* after a value has been pushed to an observable, you're better off using either `BehaviorSubject` or [`ReplaySubject`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/ReplaySubject).

I'd illustrate using `ReplaySubject` with buffer 1. It can "hold/buffer" the last emitted value and would emit to the subscribers in the future.

**Service**

```js
import { Observable, ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class RecipeService{
  private recipeSelected: ReplaySubject<string> = new ReplaySubject<string>(1);  // <-- buffer 1
  public recipeSelected$: Observable<string> = this.recipleSelected.asObservable();

  public setSelected(recipe: string): void {
    this.recipleSelected.next(recipe);
  }
}
```

**Component 1 (sender)**

```js
onselected(){
  this.recipeservice.setSelected("hello");
}
```

**Component 2 (recipient)**

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.recipeservice.recipeSelected$.subscribe(
    recipe => { 
      console.log(recipe);
    }
  );
}
```