# pass data from child routed component to parent component

Tags: angular, data-binding, router-outlet

Starting in angular, I am faced with the following difficulty: I have to pass a data from a child routed component to a parent component.

I thought I could use @Output with a eventEmitter. But I feel like it’s not possible
I also tried to use a topic that generates a change detection error (an ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError).

ts of child compo :

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.itemsMenu = this.rayonService.itemsMenu;
    this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      let paramUrlZone = params.get('id');

      if (paramUrlZone !== null) {
        this.isTest = true; // pass to the parent
      }
    });
    this.initRefForm();
  }
```

html parent (child compo is routed...)

```
------------------------------------
      <div class="router-container">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </div>
------------------------------------
```

I don't how to do the stuff..
Thanks for your help !

Comment: please show what you have done so far. Maybe this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67268840/cross-component-communication-using-emit-and-subscribe-not-working/67269104#67269104

Comment: thanks for the link, I’ll go and see

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid passing id to the parent by directly subscribing to the child's params data in the parent component like this:

```
constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) {
  route.firstChild.params.subscribe((params) => {
    console.log(params.id);
  });
}
```

Comment: ok, thanks for your answer, I’ll try, but I’m not sure it works to get the isTest variable.