# The arrow function inside the subscribe method is being called inmediatly

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I have an angular dialog that uses `ngrx` to call an API.

The `registerEvents` is only about adding two subscriptions to an array, is only called in the constructor

But for some reason the code inside the fat-arrow of the two subscribes is getting called as soon as the dialog opens, I would expect only one "new data" message instead of two.

[image: consoleMessages]

Is almost like the `registerEvents` is executing the arrow functions or that the actions are being dispached automagically

```js
constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
    private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ScheduledAppointmentsDialogComponent>,
    private orderStore$: Store<OrdersState.State>)
{
    this.registerEvents();
}

registerEvents() {
    this.subscriptions.push(this.apptsForOrder$.subscribe((apptsForOrder: any[]) => {
      console.log("new data");
      this.apptsForOrder = apptsForOrder;
    }));

    this.subscriptions.push(this.updateAttachedAppointment$.subscribe((attachAppointment: boolean) => {
      console.log({ attachAppointment: attachAppointment });
      this.toogleLinkStatus();
    }, (err) => { console.log(err) }));

  }

ngOnInit(): void {
    // other code 
    this.loadApptsForOrder();
    // other code 
}

loadApptsForOrder() {
    this.orderStore$.dispatch(OrdersActions.loadApptsForOrder({ orderId: this.orderId }));
}
```

The `loadApptsForOrder` is only being called inside the `onInit` but there are two "new data" messages

I have tried changing from mergeMap to switchMap without any effect

```js
attachAppointment$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(actions.attachAppointment),
    mergeMap(args => this.orderService.attachAppointment(args.attachAppointmentRequest)
        .pipe(
            map(response => actions.attachAppointmentComplete({ attachAppointmentResponse: response.statusCode })),
            catchError(() => of(actions.attachAppointmentFailure({ error: 'fail' })))
        )
    )
));
```

Could this be an error with the way I have implemented the service/store ? in the way that I'm subscribing or what else ?

`apptsForOrder$` and `orderStore$` are `observables<T>`

```
  private apptsForOrder$ = this.orderStore$.select(OrdersSelectors.getApptsForOrder);
  private updateAttachedAppointment$ = this.orderStore$.select(OrdersSelectors.updateAttachedAppointment);
```

Comment: Is apptsForOrder$ a BehaviourSubject? See this "Upon subscription, it returns the last value of the subject. A regular observable only triggers when it receives an onnext" -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494058/behaviorsubject-vs-observable

Comment: That means, in Beahaviour Subjects , the callback is executed when subscribing and when the subject has a new value. In Subjects, the callback is executed only when the subject has a new value.

Comment: @ConradoLopez - `apptsForOrder$` and `orderStore$` are `observables<T>` - I have added their declarations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is apptsForOrder$ a BehaviourSubject? In Beahaviour Subjects the callback is executed when subscribing and when the subject has a new value. In Subjects, the callback is executed only when the subject has a new value.

See this: [BehaviorSubject vs Observable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494058/behaviorsubject-vs-observable)

Comment: `apptsForOrder$` and `orderStore$` are `observables<T>` I have updated my question

Answer (score 1):

NgRx selectors will start emitting values directly after subscription made. the first value emit is store current value. to disable this behavior on your component you can use RxJs operator `skip(1)` before subscribe.