# Why do I get "undefined" from the Observable in auth guard when using pipe(), while subscribe() works but I get an error?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm building an authentication app using the PEAN stack (i.e., PostgreSQL - ExpressJS - Angular - NodeJS).

#### Problem

I have a problem with my auth guard:

- If I use `subscribe()`, I get the expected result in the console. *✔ - WORKING*
- If I use `pipe()`, I get `undefined` in the console. *✖ - NOT WORKING*

**if-signed-in.guard.ts**

```
import { CanActivateFn } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth/auth.service';
import { inject } from '@angular/core';
import { tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

export const IfSignedIn: CanActivateFn = (route, state) => {
  const auth = inject(AuthService);
  const router = inject(Router);
    
  auth.getSignInStatusObserver().subscribe((res: any) => {
    console.log(res);
  });

  return auth.getSignInStatusObserver().pipe(
    tap((status) => {
      console.log(status);
    }),
    map((status) => {
      console.log(status);
      if (status) {
        if (status.success === true) {
          return true;
        } else {
          router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
          return false;
        }
      } else {
        router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
        return false;
      }
    })
  );
};
```

**Screenshot:**

[image: Screenshot]

#### What I've tried

I tried implementing the same logic inside `subscribe()`:

**if-signed-in.guard.ts**

```
import { CanActivateFn } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth/auth.service';
import { inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

export const IfSignedIn: CanActivateFn = (route, state) => {
  const auth = inject(AuthService);
  const router = inject(Router);

  auth.getSignInStatusObserver().subscribe((res: any) => {
    if (res) {
      if (res.success === true) {
        return true;
      } else {
        router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
      return false;
    }
  });
};
```

But I get the following error:

> src/app/auth/guards/if-signed-in.guard.ts:7:14 - error TS2322: Type
> '(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) => void'
> is not assignable to type 'CanActivateFn'.   Type 'void' is not
> assignable to type 'boolean | UrlTree | Observable<boolean | UrlTree>
> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree>'.
>
> 7 export const IfSignedIn: CanActivateFn = (route, state) => {

#### Question

**Why do I get *undefined* from the Observable in auth guard when using `pipe()`, while `subscribe()` works but I get an error?**

---

**EDIT 1**

I've tried the code suggested by @MatthieuRiegler, but I'm still getting exactly the same response as in the screenshot above.

**if-signed-in.guard.ts**

```
import { CanActivateFn } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth/auth.service';
import { inject } from '@angular/core';
import { filter, tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

export const IfSignedIn: CanActivateFn = (route, state) => {
  const auth = inject(AuthService);
  const router = inject(Router);

  auth.getSignInStatusObserver().subscribe((res: any) => {
    console.log(res);
  });

  return auth.getSignInStatusObserver().pipe(
    filter((status) => status !== undefined),
    tap((status) => {
      console.log(status);
    }),
    map((status) => {
      console.log(status);
      if (status) {
        if (status.success === true) {
          return true;
        } else {
          router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
          return false;
        }
      } else {
        router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
        return false;
      }
    })
  );
};
```

---

**EDIT 2**

My app behaves strangely. Now I have the following code:

**if-signed-in.guard.ts**

```
import { CanActivateFn } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth/auth.service';
import { inject } from '@angular/core';
import { filter, tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

export const IfSignedIn: CanActivateFn = (route, state) => {
  const auth = inject(AuthService);
  const router = inject(Router);

  return auth.getSignInStatusObserver().pipe(
    filter((status) => status !== undefined),
    tap((status) => {
      console.log('Tap: ', status);
    }),
    map((status) => {
      console.log('Map: ', status);
      if (status) {
        if (status.success === true) {
          return true;
        } else {
          router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
          return false;
        }
      } else {
        router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
        return false;
      }
    })
  );
};
```

If I click the *Edit profile* button, everything works as expected.
If I type in the search bar `http://localhost:4200/profile/edit-profile`, it looks like something is wrong with emitting values because I receive `undefined`, and because the `filter()` works, I don't get anything in the console.

Also, the same thing happens on page refresh. It seems like the auth guard isn't working on page refresh.

**Screenshot:**

[image: GIF]

---

**EDIT 3**

I use an interceptor to set sign-in status as follows:

**sign-in-status.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpEvent, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/auth/services/auth/auth.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class SignInStatusService implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(httpRequest: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(httpRequest).pipe(
      tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse && httpRequest.url.endsWith('api/get-user') && event.status === 200) {
          this.authService.setSignInStatus({ success: true, response: event.body });
        }
      }),
      catchError((err: any) => {
        if (httpRequest.url.endsWith('api/get-user')) {
          this.authService.setSignInStatus({ success: false, response: err });
        }
        return throwError(() => err);
      })
    );
  }

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}
}
```

Comment: `CanActivateFn` needs to return a value (`boolean` or `Observable<boolean>`) so the subscribe is not an option.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler Thanks for the response. Yeah, I understand that from the error message. The problem is that `pipe()` returns `undefined`. Why?

Comment: Would using a [`BehaviorSubject` instead of `Observable`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39494058/6309) help?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is elsewhere.
As you can see, you get an `undefined` as first value of your subscribe.

By doing a `subscribe` without closing it, it outlives the usage of the `CanActivateFn`.

My guess is that you are experiencing a race condition. Your observable emit a status too late for the `CanActivateFn`.

Your `getSignInStatusObserver` shouldn't emit `undefined`, you filter it `pipe(filter(status => status !== undefined)).` That should fix your issue !

Comment: I've tried the code you suggested, but I'm still getting exactly the same response as in the screenshot above. I edited my question with the code I tried.

Comment: What value do you get in your status ? btw you should return an `UrlTree` instead on `navigate()` + returning a `false`.

Comment: If I use `filter()` I don't get anything at all in the console. Nothing. If I don't use `filter()`, I get `undefined` in the console. It looks like something is wrong with emitting values because I only receive `undefined` when using `filter()` and because the filter works, I don't get anything in the console. What could be wrong?

Comment: I edited my question for the second time with additional information and a GIF so you can see what's happening. I would be really grateful for your help because I've been stuck at this point for 2 weeks now.

Comment: When does `getSignInStatusObserver` gets its value ?

Comment: The `getSignInStatusObserver` gets its value when the interceptor intercepts `status === 200` on the `api/get-user` (the backend checks for the session cookie on the `api/get-user`). So, if the cookie is present, the backend returns `200`, the interceptor intercepts that, and sets the sign-in status to `success: true`. I edited my question with `sign-in-status.service.ts`.

Comment: I'm offering a bounty now.

Comment: Is your repo publicly accessible ?

Comment: No, unfortunatelly.

Comment: have you tried removing the `navigate()` and returining a `UrlTree` instead ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254695/discussion-between-rok-benko-and-matthieu-riegler).